# How to serialize only objects id

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have two classes

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleClass
{
    public ComplexClass Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // Lots of stuff
}

... 
// and somewhere    
public static List<ComplexClass> ClassesList;
```

How to serialize `SimpleClass` so that only `Guid` is saved from complex class? How to deserialize it afterwards? Suppose I already have collection of `ComplexClass`es and only need to pick one by id.

I'm using `XmlSerializer` for serialization

Answer (score 1):

Include the Namespace System.Xml.Serialization and adding the attribute [XmlIgnore] over the field or property that you want to be excluded in Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to make a custom serialization of course using `ISerializable`, but if you want to keep it simple then something like this might work:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ComplexClass Parent { get; set; }

    public Guid ComplexClassId { 
        get { return Parent.Id; } 
        set { Parent = new ComplexClass(value); } 
    }
}
```

Or just mark the unwanted fields in ComplexClass using `XmlIgnore`.

---

I have changed my answer to use `XmlIgnore` instead of `NonSerialized` based on comment from L.B. Left the answer here because I think it still adds some info to Andypopa.

Comment: `NonSerialized` is valid only for *fields* not *properties* + XmlSerializer doesn't use it.

Comment: Seems you are right, NonSerialized only works for binary and SOAP serializers.